# Powershell Pass a csv of names, to LDAP filter by CN

Tags: powershell, filter, properties, ldap

```
$csv = Get-Content "ListOfNames.csv"

foreach($item in $csv){
Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter '(cn=$item)' -Properties * | Ft sAMAccountName, givenName, emailAddress
}
```

I'm new to powershell,
I'm trying to enter a list of users only by names by their cn parameter
I don't get any result, but when I enter a name instead of $item it works great...
What am I missing here ? can't I enter an array in the -LDAPFilter?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a string formatting issue to me.

Try this:

```
$csv = Get-Content "ListOfNames.csv"

foreach ($item in $csv) {
  $filter = [string]::Format("'(cn={0})'", $item)
  Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter $filter -Properties * | Ft sAMAccountName, givenName, emailAddress
}
```

Comment: My Man! Thank you so much for your solution, just a small remark, it worked without the single quotes in the $filter line 
Thanks again for your insights, highly appreciated.

Comment: Hey Merkle, 
Can you elaborate as to why this solution works? Can you explain the logic here so I could better understand... I mean break it down to layman's terms :)
Thanks again

Comment: The way that PowerShell handles quotes and strings can be confusing at times.
Since PowerShell is a .NET language, you can call .NET methods.
[string]::Format() is one of the ways to format a string in .NET.
In this code: [string]::Format("'(cn={0})'", $item)
{0} gets swapped out with the contents of $item.
Note that Doug Maurer's solution below would also work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use double quotes in this case for the variable to be able to expand

```
$csv = Get-Content "ListOfNames.csv"

foreach($item in $csv){
    Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(cn=$item)" -Properties emailaddress |
        Format-Table sAMAccountName, givenName, emailAddress
}
```

Also note that emailaddress is the only property from your desired output not returned by default. Try to avoid `-Properties *` unless you need all those properties.